# Parse JSON in Swift 5

Tags: json, swift, swift5

I am trying to write a generic parser for JSON files similar to this.

```
{
    "BA": {
        "name": "Bert Andries",
        "age": 40,
        "likes": ["Food"]
    },
    ...
}
```

I want to return `Dictionary<String, User>` where `User` has the properties `name`, `age` and `likes`. This is what I have now.

```swift
import Foundation

struct JsonHelper {
    static func parseJsonString<T: Decodable>(jsonString: String, entityType: T.Type) -> Dictionary<String, T> {
        let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
        let items = try! JSONDecoder().decode([entityType].self, from: jsonData)

        return items
    }

    static func parseJsonFile<T: Decodable>(file: String, entityType: T.Type) -> Dictionary<String, T> {
        if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: "json") {
            if let contents = try? String(contentsOfFile: filepath) {
                return self.parseJsonString(jsonString: contents, entityType: entityType)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Solution

With the answer from [bcal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12847064/bcal) I rewrote the `struct` to this.

```swift
import Foundation

struct JsonHelper {
    static func parseJsonString<T: Decodable>(jsonString: String, entityType: T.Type) -> Dictionary<String, T>? {
        if let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) {
            return try? JSONDecoder().decode(Dictionary<String, T>.self, from: jsonData)
        }

        return nil
    }

    static func parseJsonFile<T: Decodable>(file: String, entityType: T.Type) -> Dictionary<String, T>? {
        if let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: "json") {
            if let contents = try? String(contentsOfFile: filepath) {
                return self.parseJsonString(jsonString: contents, entityType: entityType)
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

And I can use it like this.

```swift
if let users = JsonHelper.parseJsonFile(file: "users", entityType: User.self) {
    if let user = dictionary["BA"] {
        print(user.name)
    }
}
```

The User struct could be written like this. Because of the `?` behind the properties, the decoding will be successful, even if those properties would be missing in the JSON object.

```
struct User: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let age: Int?
    let likes: [String]?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dictionary` conforms to `Encodable` and `Decodable`, so `JSONDecoder` may be used with the `Dictionary<String, User>` type.

To decode your JSON object ...

```
let jsonString = """
{
    "BA": {
        "name": "Bert Andries",
        "age": 40,
        "likes": ["FN"]
    },
    "FN": {
        "name": "Frans Niemen",
        "age": 44,
        "likes": ["BA"]
    },
    "SA": {
        "name": "Sandra Andries",
        "age": 35,
        "likes": ["BA", "FN"]
    }
}
"""

struct User: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let age: Int?
    let likes: [String]?
}

func decode(jsonString: String) throws -> Dictionary<String, User>? {
    guard let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) else {
        return nil
    }
    return try JSONDecoder().decode(Dictionary<String, User>.self, from: jsonData)
}

let dict = try? decode(jsonString: jsonString)

print("\(String(describing: dict))")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have updated the question to see if there's more improvement to be made.

Comment: @spaceflora could you be more specific about what type of improvements you're looking for?

Comment: This is the first thing I've written in Swift. So any best practices I have missed out on, let me know!

Comment: @spaceflora For your first pass at Swift you're doing a pretty good job.You're using generics, and your new version avoids the forced unwrap (!). A good practice is to force unwrapping only when you're sure of the type. You might have also noticed the optional types for the properties in  the `User` struct; this ensures that decoding will succeed even if a JSON attribute is missing from one of the encoded objects.